# Rails :How to move code from view to partial file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In edit.html.erb

```
 <% if material.look %>
        <%= form_for material do |f|%>
        <% if material.approval = "1" %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :date,value: Date.today %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :approval_amount, value: 0 %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :approval_amount_percentage, value: 0 %>
        <%= f.submit 'yes' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for material do |f|%>
        <%= f.hidden_field :approval_amount, value: 0 %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :approval_amount_percentage, value: 0 %>
        <%= f.submit 'no' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Code in two forms are duplicate, so I want to move them to partial file,
In _material_form.html.erb I code like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :approval_amount, value: 0 %>
<%= f.hidden_field :approval_amount_percentage, value: 0 %>
```

In edit.html.erb, I modifies duplicate code

```
   <% if material.look %>
        <%= form_for material do |f|%>
        <% if material.approval = "1" %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :date,value: Date.today %>
        <% end %>
        <%= render 'material_form'%>
        <%= f.submit 'yes' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for material do |f|%>
        <%= render 'material_form'%>
        <%= f.submit 'no' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

However, it shows an error

> undefined local variable or method `f' for

What causes the error and how to fix it ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form, assigned to the variable `f` is out of scope in your partial. To use it, you'll need to pass `f` in as a local value to your partial:

```
<%= render 'material_form', f: f%>
```

The rails documentation on [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) is quite helpful; you can also dig into the [action renderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) documentation if you want to go deeper.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, could you let me know where I can learn more about working with partials?

Comment: Sure thing! Updated